# How to get results from a mysql table based on the relation to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that I need to work with in this scenario: members and rank_permissions.  I want to get a list of administrators.  An admin is any member whose rank has a row in the permissions table that contains an action column of "access_admin". There could be multiple ranks that have a row that contains that permission.  How would I get rows from the members table where the rank_id has a row in the permissions table with the action of "access_admin"?

These are my tables:

```
Members: member_id, rank_id
rank_permissions: rank_id, action
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
SELECT m.member_id, m.rank_id, p.rank_id, p.action
FROM members as m
LEFT JOIN rank_permissions as p ON m.rank_id = p.rank_id
WHERE p.action = "access_admin"
```

This currently returns 0 rows, even though there is one member whose rank_id is 1 and there is a row in the permissions table with a rank_id of 1 and an action of "access_admin".  What am I doing wrong?

### Update

So my data was correct and the query was correct.  It ended up being a problem with my PHP script.  Thanks for the attempted help!

Comment: Your question is correct (although you should use an inner join).  The data is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there are unrecognized characters in the `access_permission` part.  Try this version:

```
SELECT m.member_id, m.rank_id, p.rank_id, p.action
FROM members m INNER JOIN
     rank_permissions p
     ON m.rank_id = p.rank_id
WHERE p.action LIKE '%access_admin%'
```